# What is the Fourier transform of the bump function $e^{-\frac{1}{1-|x|^2}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

Let
$$f(x):= 
\left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
    e^{-\frac{1}{1-|x|^2}}, & \hbox{$|x|<1$;} \\
    0, & \hbox{$|x|\geq1$.}
  \end{array}
\right.$$

This is a generic bump function (a smooth positive bounded function with compact support). It is a Schwartz function, so it has a Schwartz Fourier transform.

My question is about calculating its Fourier transform $\hat{f}$:

Since $f$ is radial (i.e. rotationally invariant),  then so is $\hat{f}$. So $\hat{f}(\xi)=\hat{f}(|\xi|,0,...,0)$ for all $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Therefore, denoting $x^\prime=(x_2,x_3,...,x_n)$, we have

$$\hat{f}(\xi)=\int_{|x|\leq 1}e^{\dot{\imath}x_{1}|\xi|}e^{-\frac{1}{1-|x|^2}}dx=\int_{|x|\leq 1}e^{\dot{\imath}x_{1}|\xi|}e^{-\frac{1}{1-|x|^2}}dx\\= \int_{-1}^{1}e^{\dot{\imath}x_{1}|\xi|}\int_{|x^\prime|\leq \sqrt{1-x_1^2}}e^{-\frac{1}{1-x_1^2-|x^\prime|^2}}dx^\prime dx_1\\= \int_{-1}^{1}e^{\dot{\imath}x_{1}|\xi|}\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-2}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x_1^2}}e^{-\frac{1}{1-x_1^2-\rho^2}}\rho^{n-2}d\rho d\omega_{n-2} dx_1\\
=|\mathbb{S}^{n-2}|\int_{-1}^{1}e^{\dot{\imath}x_{1}|\xi|}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x_1^2}}e^{-\frac{1}{1-x_1^2-\rho^2}}\rho^{n-2}d\rho  dx_1$$

And I am stuck here!

Comment: All smooth fuction with compact support is in particular Schwartz.

Comment: I would not hope for $\hat{f}$ to be an elementary function.

Comment: @Pires Dankan. That is true. A Shwartz function is a smooth function that decays (along with its derivatives of all orders) faster than any polynomial, and compactly supported functions are identically zero outside a compact set. Notice that the support of the function always contains the support of its derivative.